# lidar_camera_calibration (using ROS) hangs up

Tags: c++, camera, ros, freeze, lidar

I am using the following library to try to calibrate a Velodyne LiDAR to a PiCam RGB camera: https://github.com/ankitdhall/lidar_camera_calibration.  It took me a while to configure, but now everything builds and runs; however, the program is hanging up.  Here's the printouts I get when I run it.

```
user@computer$ roslaunch lidar_camera_calibration find_transform.launch
... logging to /home/manny/.ros/log/703a468e-d0dc-11e5-9811-b827eb0c153d/roslaunch-manny-13746.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://manny:33471/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /aruco_mapping/calibration_file: /home/manny/Code/...
 * /aruco_mapping/marker_size: 0.1016
 * /aruco_mapping/num_of_markers: 1
 * /aruco_mapping/roi_allowed: False
 * /aruco_mapping/space_type: plane
 * /lidar_camera_calibration/camera_frame_topic: /raspicam_node/im...
 * /lidar_camera_calibration/camera_info_topic: /raspicam_node/ca...
 * /lidar_camera_calibration/velodyne_topic: /velodyne_points
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3

NODES
  /
    aruco_mapping (aruco_mapping/aruco_mapping)
    find_transform (lidar_camera_calibration/find_transform)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://stick:11311

process[aruco_mapping-1]: started with pid [13756]
process[find_transform-2]: started with pid [13757]
Size of the frame: 1280 x 960
Limits: -2.5 to 2.5
Limits: -4 to 4
Limits: 0 to 1.7
Number of markers: 1
Intensity threshold (between 0.0 and 1.0): 0.0004
useCameraInfo: 0
Projection matrix: 
[981.17163, 0, 640, 0;
 0, 981.17163, 480, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0]
MAX_ITERS: 100
[ INFO] [1547151515.113124565]: Reading CameraInfo from configuration file
[ INFO] [1547151515.790099973]: Calibration file path: /home/manny/Code/catkin_ws/src/aruco_mapping/data/picam_calibration.ini
[ INFO] [1547151515.848735811]: Number of markers: 1
[ INFO] [1547151515.848845526]: Marker Size: 0.1016
[ INFO] [1547151515.848888023]: Type of space: plane
[ INFO] [1547151515.848919640]: ROI allowed: 0
[ INFO] [1547151515.848945892]: ROI x-coor: 0
[ INFO] [1547151515.848975687]: ROI y-coor: 0
[ INFO] [1547151515.849009739]: ROI width: 0
[ INFO] [1547151515.849052101]: ROI height: 8096
[ INFO] [1547151515.881308433]: Calibration data loaded successfully
```

It seems to me that the calibration configuration files are being loaded correctly, but that the lidar_camera_calibration program cannot "latch onto" the ROS topics (I mean, connect to and receive the data from the ROS topics that are streaming data from the live devices, LiDAR and RGB camera).  This is just a guess.  Another possibility is that the program does not give any more feedback until it finds the calibration board.  If that is the case, it is a bit unfortunate, because it would be nice to know if it is even able to read the data from the devices.  At the moment, the devices cannot even see the calibration board, but they could when a tried a few days ago.

When I list the ROS topics, I get the three that I think it needs, `/raspicam_node/camera_info`, `/raspicam_node/image/compressed`, and `/velodyne_points`.

```
user@computer$ rostopic list
/aruco_markers
/aruco_poses
/clicked_point
/diagnostics
/initialpose
/lidar_camera_calibration_rt
/move_base_simple/goal
/raspicam_node/camera_info
/raspicam_node/image/compressed
/raspicam_node/parameter_descriptions
/raspicam_node/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/tf_static
/velodyne_nodelet_manager/bond
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/parameter_descriptions
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/parameter_updates
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/parameter_descriptions
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/parameter_updates
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/parameter_descriptions
/velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/parameter_updates
/velodyne_packets
/velodyne_points
```

`lidar_camera_calibration` doesn't crash.  It just "sits there", cursor blinking.

I suppose my next step in troubleshooting will be to look more closely at their C++ code, to see where it's hanging up, and maybe add a bunch of more print-outs around there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following to see if all working as it should be:

- Check if you have data on those topics
- Check If Nodes are connected using rosnode or rqt_graph
- If it's not Check If any other topics has the data you need
- remap the topics that are empty to those that are not

if nothing worked change log level to debug (in RQT Logger plugin or any way you know) to see if there's you see any message that might help

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your reply.  As it turned out, I was using the wrong ArUco marker.  I had to change the family to "Original ArUco" at this address: http://chev.me/arucogen/

Comment: Oh, actually, the above comment represents the solution to a crash I got after I fixed the issue referred to in my question above.  It was in fact an issue related to remapping.  When I remapped to /image_raw, or something like that, it fixed that issue.